# Which annotation do i use to upload an image on GAE endpoint?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an SPI Google endpoint, I can't find any examples on which annotation to use to accept a for example a `MultipartFile file`?

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveNewBill" ,
             httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public Bill saveBillImage( @Named("content") MultipartContent f ){
      Bill bill = new Bill();
      return bill;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have just noticed, while reading up on some other things Blobstore related, that Google now recommends using Google Cloud Storage INSTEAD of the Blobstore for serving of media.

Since you are using an Endpoint on App Engine, you should use the `BlobStore`.

It is the preferred way to handle uploading, storage and retrieval of images on App Engine.

The following function in the `BlobstoreService` will generate an upload URL which you then upload the image to using a standard Multipart Request with the image data being passed in a parameter named `file`.

```
BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().createUploadUrl("/[servlet name goes here]");
```

You will need to provide the name of a Servlet to which the request will be redirected after the upload has completed. This Servlet can access the newly created Blobstore item and do something meaningful with it - such as get the serving URL of the image and return it to the client.

Here is a snippet of a Servlet that does just that:

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

            List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("file");
            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get(0);

            ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
            ServingUrlOptions servingOptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
            servingOptions.secureUrl(true);
            String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(servingOptions);

            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            res.setContentType("text/plain");

            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            out.print(servingUrl);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
    }
```

You can also add some querystring parameters of your own to the upload URL which can be read in the Servlet. This can be useful for things like attaching the BlobKey to a specific entity etc.

For a more in-depth look at the Blobstore, I recommend the following article from Romin Irani's App Engine Tutorial: https://rominirani.com/episode-13-using-the-blobstore-java-api-56423cf6a1b#.6t95vziul

Comment: ahh I see! Thank you..that makes perfect sense.